# Java set matcher results to capture pattern order

Tags: java, regex, loops

I'm not really asking about the regex pattern necessarily, but more about it's capture groups. I'm trying to associate matches with the proper capture group upon matching. for example the string `:>>>> !something! 100 num *** <<<<:` will be set into matcher groups `1-6` using this pattern:

```
(>>>>)|(!something!)|(\d{3})|(\w+)|(\*)+|(<<<<)
```

Then let's say you have the string `101 any <<<<`. It matches captures groups `3`, `4`, and `6`. The matcher puts the matches into `1`, `2`, `3`. Is it possible to set array with the matches placed in same way as the capture group - as to fill the empty elements in the array with that order? Essentially I want to call the matcher array and it come back `empty empty 101 any empty <<<<`

```
List n = new ArrayList();
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   n.add(matcher.group(i));
}
```

This works if all the capture groups are found by the matcher for the string, but doesn't work when the string is missing anything.

Comment: Why multiple groups? Can you not use: `(>>>>|!something!|\d{3}|\w+|\*+|<<<<)`?

Comment: Basically I want to be able to identify the match with the capture group that found it. Thx

Comment: The reason for not using one capture group is that `a=1`, `b=2`, `c=3`... etc. not `a=123, a=321, etc.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is java doc for [Matcher#group(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29)

> Returns the input subsequence captured by the given **group during the
>   previous match operation**. For a matcher m, input sequence s, and group
>   index g, the expressions m.group(g) and s.substring(m.start(g),
>   m.end(g)) are equivalent.
>
> **Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one.
>   Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is
>   equivalent to m.group().**
>
> If the match was successful but the group specified failed to match
>   any part of the input sequence, then null is returned. Note that some
>   groups, for example (a*), match the empty string. This method will
>   return the empty string when such a group successfully matches the
>   empty string in the input.

So in order to use capturing group concept your pattern shall match with the string fully. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(>>>>)?(!something!)?([\\d]{3})?([\\w]+)?([\\*]+)?(<<<<)");
    String s1 = ">>>>!something!100num***<<<<";

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
    if(m.matches()) {
        for(int i=1;i<=m.groupCount();i++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + m.group(i));
        }
    }

    s1 = "101any<<<<";

    m = p.matcher(s1);
    if(m.matches()) {
        for(int i=1;i<=m.groupCount();i++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + m.group(i));
        }
    }
```

Here is the output for above:

```
Group 1: >>>>
Group 2: !something!
Group 3: 100
Group 4: num
Group 5: ***
Group 6: <<<<

Group 1: null
Group 2: null
Group 3: 101
Group 4: any
Group 5: null
Group 6: <<<<
```

Hope this helps you in right direction.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that - so how do I make it match fully? That's really the question.

Comment: Please see the edited answer. hopefully its what you are looking.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer - Is it not possible to use patterns with `|` (or operators) and `\s` spaces with this solution? most of my patterns have both, and the strings usually have spaces, so everything would need to be reformatted somehow.

Comment: you do not need `|` or operator because it works differently than you need it. you can use `[ ]*` pattern in between capturing groups to exclude spaces